# Specify interface (or source IP) for request

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I have 2 network interfaces on my machine.

I want to use `aiohttp` for HTTP requests, but with control over which of the 2 interfaces the request goes through.  This is equivalent to being able to specify my source IP address, since they are on different LANs.

Here is a solution using the non-async `requests` module:

```
import requests

def session_for_src_addr(addr: str) -> requests.Session:
    session = requests.Session()
    for prefix in ('http://', 'https://'):
        session.get_adapter(prefix).init_poolmanager(
            # those are default values from HTTPAdapter's constructor
            connections=requests.adapters.DEFAULT_POOLSIZE,
            maxsize=requests.adapters.DEFAULT_POOLSIZE,
            # This should be a tuple of (address, port). Port 0 means auto-selection.
            source_address=(addr, 0),
        )

    return session

# usage example:
s = session_for_src_addr('192.168.1.12')
s.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
```

Any way to achieve similar with `aiohttp.ClientSession()`?

Comment: I have the same problem, please give us update if you have found any solution. If solution still doesn't exist, the only possibility to execute requests in different threads without aiohttp. But seems this is too complicated solution for such "easy" task.

Comment: As far I've found only this way - specify source IP, https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v3.7.4.post0/faq.html#id8

But sometimes (as in my case) there might be multiple interfaces with same IP. For example if we connect to multiple WiFi AP's with same default settings OR if we connect to multiple GoPro cameras.So this way is not acceptable for me.